# Undefined function and overload

Tags: compiler-errors, scilab

I want to draw a graph, but when I run the program in Scilab, I get this error in French:

> Opération indéfinie pour les opérandes données.
>   vérifier ou définir la fonction %b_1_s pour la surcharge.

Here is the code:

```
for t=[0:9.69:19.38]
    if 0<=t<9.69 then
        v=0;
    elseif 9.69<=t<14.45 then
        v=1.548*t;
    else
        v=15;
    end 
end
plot(t,v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that you need to overload `<` to work with booleans and numbers (double matrix, actually). It happens because in the lines `if 0<=t<9.69 then` and `elseif 9.69<=t<14.45 then` you attempt to perform two operations in a row. That's fine in Mathematical notation, but not in this case.

Scilab interprets

1. `0<=t<9.69` as `(0 <= t) < 9.69`, and
2. `9.69<=t<14.45` as `(9.69 <= t) < 14.45`.

So, the first parenthesis returns a boolean, and then you compare that said boolean to a number, which doesn't make sense. To solve it, you should use two different comparisons separated by the *and* operator `&`:

1. `0<=t<9.69` becomes `(0 <= t) & (t < 9.69)`, and
2. `9.69<=t<14.45` becomes `(9.69 <= t) & (t < 14.45)`.